# Login control - error

Tags: asp.net, login-control

There is a Login control on my ASP.NET (2.0) page. I handle LoggingIn event like this:

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{

    // go to database and find this user

    if (userTable != null && userTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(userTable.Rows[0]["UserID"]);

        HttpCookie userIdCookie = new HttpCookie("UserID", userID.ToString());
        Response.AppendCookie(userIdCookie);

     }
     else
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
     }                
 }
```

User found in database. And at the end of this function e.Cancel still set to false. But then occured LoginError. LoggedIn doesn't occured. And FailureText appears on the page. I don't know how to debug this :(

Comment: you might want to have a look through this article that explains Forms Authetication reasonably well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, could you elaborate on what LoginError is ?
Also what is LoggedIn and FailureText - I guess they're sort off self explanatory, however the more you explain, the less we have to guess :-)

Comment: LoginError is the event raised when a login failed and FailureText is a property of the Login control that can be used to relay a reason for the failed login to the user. Both are to do with ASP.NET's Login control - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you also handled the `Authenticate` event?

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server"
            OnAuthenticate="MyOnAuthenticate">


private void MyOnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    isAuthenticated = YourAuthenticationMethod(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);

    e.Authenticated = isAuthenticated;
}

private bool YourAuthenticationMethod(string UserName, string pwd)
{
    // Insert code that implements a site-specific custom 
    // authentication method here.             
}
```

[LoginControl's Authenticated event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx)